# Why does factoring eliminate a hole in the limit?

Tags: calculus, limits, intuition, factoring

$$\lim _{x\rightarrow 5}\frac{x^2-25}{x-5}  = \lim_{x\rightarrow 5} (x+5)$$

I understand that to evaluate a limit that has a zero ("hole") in the denominator we have to factor and cancel terms, and that the original limit is equal to the new and simplified limit. I understand how to do this procedurally, but I'd like to know *why* this works. I've only been told the methodology of expanding the $x^2-25$ into $(x-5)(x+5)$, but I don't just want to understand the methodology which my teacher tells me to "just memorize", I really want to know what's going on. I've read about factoring in abstract algebra, and about irreducible polynomials (just an example...), and I'd like to get a *bigger picture* of the abstract algebra in order to see why we factor the limit and why the simplified is equal to the original if it's missing the $(x-5)$, which has been cancelled. I don't want to just memorize things, I would really like to understand, but I've been told that this is "just how we do it" and that I should "practice to just memorize the procedure."
I really want to understand this in abstract algebra terms, please elaborate. Thank you very much.

Comment: Very laudable that you want to understand instead of "just memorize".

Comment: The expression $\frac{(x+5)(x-5)}{x-5}=x+5$, just so long as $x\neq 5$, since $\frac{(x+5)(x-5)}{x-5}$ has the bad fortune of not being defined at $x=5$.

Comment: I don't understand what your question is.  Are you asking why the function $\frac{x^2-25}{x-5}$ is undefined at $x=5$?  or why we're allowed to cancel $(x-5)$ from the top and bottom?  or why the limits before and after cancellation are equal?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft yes, all of those questions I'm asking :)

Comment: To answer the question - I've only been told the methodology of expanding the x2−25 into (x−5)(x+5). It goes like this: (in reverse)

(x-5)(x+5) = x(x+5)-5(x+5) = x^2+5x-5x-25 = x^2-25

So, working above the other way takes x^2-25 back to (x-5)(x+5)

Comment: Similar to:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1455579/why-do-fx-frac-x%C2%B2-1x-1-and-gx-x1-not-have-the-same-domain-o/1455583#comment2964553_1455583

Comment: Srongly related to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1525054/why-are-removable-discontinuities-even-discontinuities-at-all

Comment: I got the wisdom about this from True Lord Jesus Christ. Look for your equation. There are 3 equation: whole equattion, the dividend equation and the divisor equation. If we input 5 to the whole equatino, then the dividend equation is the one responsible for generating 0/0. Hence, we must get rid that dividend equation from the whole equation.

Answer (score 145):

This [image of mine](http://daylateanddollarshort.com/bloog/limits-are-about-the-journey/) seems apropos:

[image: Limits are about the journey ...]

In the case of $\lim_{x\to 5} \frac{x^2-25}{x-5}$, the message here is: *Away from* $x=5$, the function $\frac{x^2-25}{x-5}$ is completely identical to $x+5$; thus, what we *expect to find* as we *approach* $x=5$ is the value $5+5$. This *anticipated* value is what a limit computes.

The fact that the original function isn't defined at $x=5$ is immaterial. [Walley World](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Lampoon%27s_Vacation) may be closed for repairs when you arrive, but that doesn't mean you and your dysfunctional family didn't spend an entire cross-country road trip anticipating all the fun you'd have there.

Comment: Extremely helpful answer as always, Blue. You're incredible at understanding what people are really asking and providing strong intuition. Thank you for your contribution to this site!

Comment: @Blue Your answer made me think something: Can we always find another function which - away from a certain value - is completely identical to the former function? I mean, what is done in this example is the following: We have an algebraic expression and we can find another algebraic expression  that have that property.

Comment: BTW: I read your image as the jingles in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xuCn8ux2gbs).

Comment: Super answer...the craziest I ever read in here

Comment: @Blue: Shameless plug: A downloadable poster version of the "Journey/Destination" image is available at [my Etsy shop](https://etsy.com/listing/810313134), and a t-shirt is available from [Spring](https://inspired-by-math.creator-spring.com/listing/limits-journey). (I'll delete this comment if there are objections.)

Answer (score 144):

First, and *by definition*, when dealing with

$$\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)$$

we *must* assume $\,f\,$ is defined in some neighborhood of $\,x_0\,$ **except** , perhaps, on $\,x_0\,$ itself, and from here that in the process of taking the limit we have the right and the duty to assume $\,x\,$ approaches $\,x_0\,$ in any possible way **but it is never equal to it**.

Thus, and since in our case we *always* have $\,x\ne x_0=5\,$ during the limit process , we can algebraically cancel for the whole process.

$$\frac{x^2-25}{x-5}=\frac{(x+5)\color{red}{(x-5)}}{\color{red}{x-5}}=x+5\xrightarrow[x\to 5]{}10$$

The above process shows that the original function behaves **exactly** as the straight line $\,y=x+5\,$ **except** at the point $\,x=5\,$ , where there exists "a hole", as you mention.

Comment: said hole can, of course be filled in by plugging it with the limit ...

Comment: Some definitions of the limit do not require that we consider points that are not equal to $x_0$. How do you handle these cases then? The definition goes as $\lim f(x) = L$ provided for each $\epsilon\gt 0$ there is some $\delta \gt 0$ such that $\vert x - x_0\vert \lt \delta\ldots$ and so on.

Comment: @AlexOrtiz The epsilon delta definition of the limit for general metric spaces has $0 < d(x,c) < \delta$. Note the first inequality, which implies $x \neq c$.

Answer (score 33):

Let's consider a simpler example first.  Consider the function $f(x) = \frac{2x}x$.  This says you take some number $x$, multiply by 2, then divide by the original number $x$.  Obviously the answer is always 2, right?  Except that when $x$ is zero, the division is forbidden and there is no answer at all. But for every $x$ except 0, we have $\frac{2x}x = 2$. In particular, for values of $x$ close to, but not equal to 0, we have $\frac{2x}x = 2$.

The function $\frac{x^2-25}{x-5}$ is similar, just a little more complicated.  Calculating $x^2-25$ always gives you the same as $(x-5)(x+5)$.  That is, if you take $x$, square it, and subtract 25, you always get the same number as if you take $x$, add 5 and subtract 5, and then multiply the two results.  So we can replace $x^2-25$ with $(x+5)(x-5)$ because they always give the same number regardless of what you start with; they are two ways of getting to the same place.  And then we see that $$\frac{x^2-25}{x-5} = \frac{(x+5)(x-5)}{x-5} = x+5$$

except that if $x-5$ happens to be zero (that is, if $x=5$) the division by zero is forbidden and we get nothing at all.  But for any other $x$ the result of $\frac{x^2-25}{x-5}$ is always exactly equal to $x+5$. In particular, for values of $x$ close to, but not equal to 5, we have $\frac{x^2-25}{x-5} = x+5 $.

The limit $$\lim_{x\to 5} \ldots$$
asks 
 what happens to some function when $x$  close to, but not exactly equal to 5.  And while this function is undefined for $x=5$, because to calculate it  you would have to divide by zero, it is perfectly well-behaved for *other* values of $x$, and in particular for values of $x$ close to 5.  For values of $x$ close to 5 it is equal to $x+5$, and so for values of $x$ close to 5 it is close to 10.  And that is exactly what the limit is calculating.

Answer (score 25):

I think that what confuses you is the difference between "solving the algebraic expression", and "finding the limit". Given:

$$f_1=\frac{x^2-25}{x-5} \quad f_2 = (x+5)$$

Then, $f_1$ and $f_2$ are most definitely NOT the same function. This is because they have different domains: 5 is not a member of the domain of $f_1$, but it is in the domain of $f_2$.

However, when we go from:
$$\lim _{x\rightarrow 5}\frac{x^2-25}{x-5} \quad to \quad \lim _{x\rightarrow 5}\frac{(x-5)(x+5)}{x-5} \quad to \quad \lim_{x\rightarrow 5} (x+5)$$

We are not saying that the expressions inside the limits are equal; maybe they are, maybe they are not. What we are saying that *they have the same limit*. Totally different statement.

Above, the transformation of the second expression to the third one allows us to find a different function for which a) we know that the limit is the same, and b) we know how to trivially calculate that limit.

The big question, then: *what transformations can I make to the function $f_1$ so that the limit stays the same?* I think this is usually poorly explained in introductory courses -- a lot of hand-waving going on.

Obviously you can do any algebraic manipulation that leaves $f_1$ unchanged. You can also make any manipulation that removes and/or introduces discontinuities (points for which the function does not exist), as long as the new function stays continuous for an arbitrarily small neighborhood around $a$ (except possibly at $a$ itself). Your example is a case of such a transformation.

Here I'm myself cheating because I'm not defining 'continuity' for you. I'm sorry; please use an intuitition of what continuous means ("no holes, no jumps"), until you are presented with a formal one.

More complex transformations exist, but they have to be justified individually. You'll get to them eventually.

Comment: you clarified a lot, thanks

Comment: Sixth line from the end - "You" will be "Your".

Comment: @MrAP, thanks. You should feel free to post an edit directly

Answer (score 18):

Here's the basic idea: You're given a rational function, $f\colon \Bbb R \setminus \{5\}\to \Bbb R$, which is continuous everywhere in its domain.

You want to find the limit of that function at $5$.

One way to do that is to construct a *continuous extension* of that function, $g\colon \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$, such that $g(x) = f(x)$ whenever $x$ is in the domain of $f$. Then $$\lim_{x\to 5}f(x) = \lim_{x\to 5} g(x) = g(5).$$

In this case, factoring and cancelling accomplishes that objective.

Comment: i really like this idea of a "continuous extension", what is the formal name of this rule/theorem? I'd like to read more about it. Thanks for the answer @dfeuer

Comment: @user4150: Try this google search: ["removable discontinuity" "continuous extension"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22removable+discontinuity%22+%22continuous+extension%22)

Answer (score 12):

The chill pill you are looking for is

> If $f_1$ = $f_2$ except at $a$ then $\lim _{x{\rightarrow}a}f_1(x)=\lim_{x{\rightarrow}a}f_{2}(x)$

Comment: Yes! You made my day!

Comment: Assuming both function to be continuous at $x=a$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe, not true, nowhere in the answer does it say that the limits are $f_1(a)$ or $f_2(a)$.

Answer (score 7):

Intuitively, we can start the other way round, by simply considering $\lim_{x\rightarrow 5} (x+5)$ which we're all agreed we understand. Now consider, independently,

$$\frac{x-5}{x-5}$$

this is obviously 1 everywhere, except where it's undefined at $x = 5$. So, what would you expect to be the effect of multiplying the two? It's just multiplying by 1, *except* that it also introduces a hole at $x = 5$

Answer (score 5):

To understand this more broadly, it is convenient to check [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule), which basically boils down to this:

Given a function $f(x)=\frac{g(x)}{h(x)}$, where for some $x=x_0$ both $g(x_0)=0$ and $h(x_0)=0$, the actual value $f(x_0)$ can be obtained as*

$$\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x) = \lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{g'(x)}{h'(x)}$$

(where the prime denotes [derivation by $x$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative)) Note that if $g'(x_0)=0=h'(x_0)$, you can re-apply the same rule again and again until either numerator or denominator are not 0. In your example, we get

$$\lim_{x\to 5}\frac{x^2-25}{x-5} = \lim_{x\to 5}\frac{2x}{1}=10=\lim_{x\to5}\,(x+5)$$

To get an even deeper understanding, the [rule's proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule#Proof_of_l.27H.C3.B4pital.27s_rule) might be an interesting read.

---

*: This is only one case, you can also have $|g(x_0)|=|h(x_0)|=\infty$, but *not* $g(x_0)=0$ and $f(x_0)=\pm\infty$

Comment: I don't think it's appropriate to bring up L'Hôpital in a question like this. To justify the rule, the reader needs to be familiar with derivatives, differentiability, the sandwich theorem and Cauchy's mean value theorem just to get started. The OP is asking for understanding, not higher-level magic hand-waving. L'Hôpital's rule is a great practical tool, but it's also wielded too often as a substitute for thinking.

Comment: @EuroMicelli Woah there, I didn't intend to hand-wave magically, I just wanted to provide a different answer that, if one is interested enough, can not only explain the removable singularities in polynomial fractions but also in more complicated cases. Though I agree one shouldn't blindly apply Hôpital to just anything if there is another maybe more elegant way

Comment: Also you don't obtain the $f(x_0)$ value - you get $f(x_0)$ value provided it is _defined_ and $f$ is _continous_. The OP function is not defined at $5$ but it's limit is.

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka True, stricly speaking the example function is equivalent to $$f(x) = \begin{cases} x+5 & x\neq 5 \\ \text{undefined} & x = 5\end{cases}$$ but the singularity at $x=5$ is removable as in $$f(x)= \begin{cases}\tfrac{x^2-25}{x-5} & x\neq 5 \\ 10 & x=5 \end{cases} \Rightarrow f(x) \equiv x+5$$ But you're right that one should always keep removed singularities in mind as they may have severe influence to e.g. applications in Physics (though I can't tell one ad hoc)

Answer (score 4):

[One of definitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%28%CE%B5,_%CE%B4%29-definition_of_limit) of $\lim_{x \to A} f(x) = B$ is:

$$\forall_{\varepsilon > 0}\exists_{\delta > 0}\forall_{0 < \left|x - A\right| < \delta}\left|f(x) - B\right| < \varepsilon$$

The intuition is that we can achieve arbitrary 'precision' (put in bounds on y axis) provided we get close enough (so we get the bounds on x axis). However the definition does not say anything about the value at the point $f(A)$ which can be undefined or have arbitrary value.

One of method of proving the limit is to find the directly $\delta(\varepsilon)$. Hence we have following formula (well defined as $x\neq 5$):

$$\forall_{0 < \left|x - 5\right| < \delta}\left|\frac{x^2-25}{x-5} - 10\right| < \epsilon$$

As $x\neq 5$ (in such case $\left|x - 5\right| = 0$) we can factor the expression out

$$\forall_{0 < \left|x - 5\right| < \delta} \left|x + 5 - 10\right| < \varepsilon $$
$$\forall_{0 < \left|x - 5\right| < \delta} \left|x - 5 \right| < \varepsilon $$

Taking $\delta(\varepsilon) = \varepsilon$ we find that:

$$\forall_{\varepsilon > 0}\exists_{\delta > 0}\forall_{0 < \left|x - 5\right| < \delta}\left|\frac{x^2-25}{x-5} - 10\right| < \varepsilon$$

The key thing is that we don't care about value at the limit.

Answer (score 3):

Look at this example:

$$ \lim _{\text{thing} \to zero}(\dfrac{\text{Thing}}{\text{Thing}}) \cdot \text{Another thing}$$

Here our $\text{'Thing'}$ is **tending** to zero, but not zero, it is something *real*, call it a real $\text{Thing}$, which can be cancelled merrily.

Comment: What do you have against using letters as variables?

Answer (score 3):

The hole doesn't always disappear but when it does it is because one expression is equivalent to another except right at that hole. For example
$$\frac{x^2 - 25}{x - 5}= \frac{(x+5)(x-5)}{x-5}= (x + 5)$$
everywhere except at x = 5. However, if we are very close to 5 and we had infinite place arithmetic (as we do theoretically) the calculation of the first expression $\frac{x^2 - 25} {x - 5}$ would be very close to the last expression $(x+5)$, that is the limit as x approaches 5 of the first expression is the same limit as the limit as x approaches 5 of last expression. Since that latter is a 'nice number', we can define the value at 5 for the first expression and remove the "everywhere except at $x = 5$" by just putting 10 as the value and not calculating it.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to think of limit a bit differently: **A limit is the value a function would have at a point were it continuous at that point, with nothing else being different.**

You can see this by comparing the epsilon-delta definitions of the two concepts. We say $f$ *is continuous at* $c$, if $f$ is defined at $c$ and for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that

$|f(x) – f(c)| < \epsilon$ whenever $0 < |x – c| < \delta$.

Likewise, $f$ *has limit* $L$ *at* $c$ if for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that

$|f(x) – L| < \epsilon$ whenever $0 < |x – c| < \delta$.

Thus, *if* we have a function with isolated gaps and there is a *different* function $f^{*}$ such that

1. $f^{*}(x) = f(x)$ wherever $f(x)$ is defined and continuous,
2. $f^{*}$ is defined and continuous *everywhere*, i.e. has domain $\mathbb{R}$ (versus the original function having domain $\mathbb{R}$ minus a set of isolated points),

then we *must* have that the value this $f^{*}$ takes at the points where $f$ was *not* defined *or* continuous must be the limiting values at those points.

And that's what you find by cancellation: by rewriting the expression describing the function in a form that involves only addition and multiplication with no division, you have created a formula that describes a function that must agree where the division part is defined, but since no division is involved, is defined everywhere. Moreover, since addition and multiplication (and powers, though you can consider them repeated multiplication) are continuous, then it follows that this function must be continuous as well. Hence the above are met, and the holes fill in.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that if two functions $f$ and $g$ differ only at $a$ but are identical otherwise, we have $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} f(x) = \lim_{x \to a} g(x)$. In this case $f(x) = \dfrac {x^2-25}{x-5}$ and $g(x) = x+5$ are identical everywhere except $x=5$, so $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 5} \dfrac {x^2-25}{x-5} = \lim_{x \to 5} x+5 = 10.$

Answer (score 0):

In limits the value of x is always tending and not exact

x→a means the value of x tends to a. Similarly  x→5 means tending to 5. So basically the value of x is not 5, but a little more or less than 5.

Hence you cannot take the denominator 0 in any case as the denominator will be, again, tending to zero. That is why we try to factorize the numerator first in order to check if there are any terms common both on the numerator and the denominator.

Answer (score 0):

$$L:=\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)$$ is the value that would make $f$ continuous at $x_0$.

If you known another function $g$ which is continuous and coincides with $f$ around $x_0$, then perforce

$$L=g(x_0).$$

Answer (score 0):

## Here's the actual rigorous reason that leaves out no detail.

> **A part of the Algebraic Limit Theorem for Functional limits:**
> $$\lim_{x \to a}(f(x)g(x))=\lim_{x \to a}f(x)\lim_{x \to a}g(x)$$ if both $\lim\limits_{x \to a}f(x)\text{ and }\lim\limits_{x \to a}g(x)$ exist.

> **Claim:** $\lim\limits_{x \to a}\frac{x - a}{x-a}$ exists and equals to $1$.

*Proof:* from definition of a limit, $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x) = b$ means $\forall \epsilon > 0: \exists \ \delta > 0 \text{ such that } 0 < \vert x-a\vert<\delta \implies \vert f(x) - b\vert < \epsilon$.
Let $\epsilon > 0$. Choose $\delta = 1$(we can choose any positive number, in fact).  If
$0 < \vert x - a \vert < 1$ then $0 < \vert x - a \vert$, so $\vert x - a \vert \neq 0 \implies \frac{x - a}{x - a} = 1 \implies \vert \frac{x - a}{x - a} - 1\vert < \epsilon$, which concludes the proof of our claim.

Finally,

$\lim\limits_{x \to a}\frac{(x - a)f(x)}{x-a} = \lim\limits_{x \to a}\frac{x - a}{x-a} \lim\limits_{x \to a}f(x) = \lim\limits_{x \to a}f(x)$, provided that $\lim\limits_{x \to a}f(x)$ exists.

Comment: There is nothing non-rigorous about concluding that functions $f,g\colon \mathbb R\setminus\{5\}\to\mathbb R$, $f(x) = \frac{x^2-25}{x-5}$, $g(x) = x+5$ are equal functions. We can also look at $\tilde g\colon \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$, $\tilde g(x) = x+5$, which is continuous extension of $g$ on whole of $\mathbb R$. Then, $\lim_{x\to 5} g(x) = \lim_{x\to 5}\tilde g(x)$ is trivially true since for limits we are only looking at points $x\neq 5$, and $g(x) = \tilde g(x)$ when $x\neq 5$, which is precisely what you did anyway, but you added unnecessary step (product of limits).

Comment: @Ennar sure, the justification you referenced is rigorous, however, my answer at least contains a fundamental explanation as to why "the fact is trivially true since we are looking at the points $x \neq 5$". I'm not claiming that all other answers are some handwavy fluff. I simply provided as much detail as possible in order to justify the statement. Also, the product of limits is definitely not a unnecessary step. At least in my proof. With the reasoning you referenced, it is indeed not needed

Comment: I don't have problem with your answer, it's correct, just with your big bold "clickbaity" title that kind of suggests that 15 other answers here didn't provide rigorous reasoning, which is unfair characterization.

Comment: @Ennar my big bold suggests that my answer is the most fundamental, from the very definition. If I myself were to read the other answers during the very beginning of my "analysis journey", being confused with the question OP asked, I'm not sure I'd have been able to figure that out. That's why I provided my answer. By the way, I don't think clickbait on a 10 year old question will work out that well. I just think if someone needs an answer to this question, he's gonna definitely understand my answer right away

Comment: I don't think there's anything fundamental about introducing product rule when almost no one solves these problems like that. It's not incorrect, but it's not fundamental. You might as well showed directly that $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{(x-a)f(x)}{x-a}  = \lim_{x\to a}f(x)$, the product rule is unnecessary. The fundamental concept here is that of a removable singularity and that we can switch function with its continuous extension when finding limits, which ironically, is a detail you never mention.

Comment: I did mention it when dealing with nonzero absolute value in the definition of a limit