# justification of a limit

Tags: derivatives, infinity

I encountered something interesting when trying to differentiate $F(x) = c$.

Consider: $\lim_{x→0}\frac0x$.

I understand that for any $x$, no matter how incredibly small, we will have $0$ as the quotient. But don't things change when one takes matters to infinitesimals?
I.e. why is the function $\frac0x = f(x)$, not undefined at $x=0$?

I would appreciate a strong logical argument for why the limit stays at $0$.

Comment: +1, I like this question. (I fear there might be duplicates, although I didn't find any.) Plus it's one of the few here to which I know the answer and no one answered yet. `:)`

Comment: You may also benefit from ["Why does factoring eliminate a hole in the limit?"](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/462199/why-does-factoring-eliminate-a-hole-in-the-limit). I particularly like the ["limits are about the journey"](http://daylateanddollarshort.com/bloog/limits-are-about-the-journey/) image in the answer from @Blue .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The limits are not about a value at a point, but about the values **approaching** that point.

> I.e. why is the function $\frac0x = f(x)$, not undefined at $x=0$?

It **is** undefined at that point. However, its "neighbourhood" is defined, and that's what the limit gives you.

Thus $\lim_{x\to0}\frac0x=0$ means that $x$ approaching $0$ from both sides results in the same value, $0$, the limit must be defined from both sides and equal, i.e. the function is continuous in there, $\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac0x=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac0x=\lim_{x\to0}\frac0x=0$.

### Edit:

This function ($f(x)=\frac0x$), alike $\frac1x$, is continuous in its domain, $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$. (it can't really be continuous for $x=0$, because $0$ is outside it's domain) And so I see the confusion, as $\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac1x=+\infty$. One could naïvely think this is because $\frac10=\infty$, but that is (if taken literally) [outside](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line) the standard definition of the real numbers, and regarding limits, an abuse of notation for $\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac1x$. Unknowingly, one might have expected $\lim_{x\to0}\frac0x$ to be a thing of that sort ($\infty$, or at least undefinition of the limit), but as I said in the beginning, that's not what limits are about.

Besides what I have said, I was going to include something with the [$(\varepsilon,\delta)$-definition of limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%28%CE%B5,_%CE%B4%29-definition_of_limit), but I don't know it very well and it is quite confusing. So, I'll follow the initial infinitesimal spirit of Calculus, now present in the more intuitive [Non-standard analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_analysis). We know $\forall x\in\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}, \frac0x=0$. Imagine $x$ is a very small number. No matter whether $x$ is positive or negative, and no matter how small, $\frac0x$ will be $0$. That means the stated property is extensible beyond $\mathbb R$. The limit is essentially another interpretation of that, denying numbers smaller than all reals by using numbers without a fixed value ($x\to0$ instead of fixed infinitesimal $x$). Sorry for not adding a formal theoretical basing to this yet, I'll try to do it ASAP.

Comment: I think maybe I should talk more about continuity. I'll research and develop the answer, it still seems rather "dry" to me.

Answer (score 4):

Note that writing $f(x) = \frac0x$ results in $f(0) = \frac00$ wich *is* undefined. However, the singularity of $f$ is nice in the way that is can be continuously defined by $f(0) := 0$ (note the colon for *defining* the value). A limit is exactly this concept: What is the value of $f(x)$ when $x$ comes arbitrarily close to $0$, but **not** equal to $0$. The statement
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac0x = 0$$
Means exactly that, and not, as you might think $\frac00 = 0$. The misconception is that
$$\lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \neq \frac{\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)}{\lim_{x\to x_0} g(x)}$$
For general $f,g$ (even if both are continuous!). This only works when $\lim_{x\to x_0} g(x) \neq 0$, wich is not the case in your example.

Answer (score 2):

You are in fact considering function $f: \mathbb R \setminus \{0\} \mapsto \mathbb R$ that is defined $f(x) = \frac 0x$ so it i equal $0$ on all its domain. Lets look at limit $\lim \limits_{x \rightarrow 0^+} f(x)$. Function is identically equal $0$ on every open interval $(0,\varepsilon)$ for $\varepsilon>0$. Hence right side limit is equal $0$. By analogy we also have  $\lim \limits_{x \rightarrow 0^-} f(x)=0$. Whether there exists limit $\lim \limits_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x)$ is now a matter of convention. According to how I was taught it has no sense to talk about a limit of function outside its domain. But if you think otherwise, then since both one-sided limits exist and are equal $0$ the limit exists and is equal $0$.

Comment: A limit of functions outside its domain is a very interesting concept, actually. This allows you to talk about $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ where ${\rm dom}(f) \subset \mathbb R \not\ni \infty$

Comment: Well, in my poit of view $\lim \limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)$ is improper limit, defined dfferently:
$\forall \varepsilon >0 \exists N \in \mathbf R \forall x >N \; |a-f(x)| < \varepsilon$

Comment: You can define limits via neighborhoods and neighborhoods of $\infty$ are defined for $\mathbb R$ ;) But there are plenty of other limits "outside the domain". For example in the context of approximative units, such as the Poisson kernel.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is if you look at the function $f(x,y)=y/x$ then when you approach $(0,0)$ this should be invariant to the path you take in your case you walk along the path where $y=0$ (constant $0$) but when approaching over the path $y=x$ then it is constant $1$. So we say it is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

When we deal with limits we first see the result of the part after the sign $\lim$. In this case we have $\frac{0}{x}=0$. Than we have $\lim_{x\to0}{\frac{0}{x}}=\lim_{x\to0}0=0$.

Answer (score 0):

A function isn't just an expression, but you can think whether a single expression can be applied to an argument. The expression $0^{-1}$ is rather meaningless, so you don't know how to get the behavior of the function $f(x)=0\cdot x^{-1}$ at $x=0$ from the expression.

Limits are just a way to describe the behavior (if it looks consistent enough that the limit exists) **around** the point. It doesn't state anything about the value of the function at the point. That is if
$a=\lim_{x\to b}f(x)$
then the function $f_1(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}f(x)&\text{ if }x\neq b\\a&\text{ if }x=b\end{matrix}\right.$ is continuous.