# Wouldn't $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(-4+h)^2-16}{h}$ be $0/0$ or "Does Not Exist"?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

[image]

I got $(16-16)/0$. Am I wrong to have this conclusion, or am I correct and the answer somehow isn't "DNE" but instead $0$?

Comment: you can try plotting the expression.

Comment: How about simplifying the expression? You should get something with a factor of *h* in the numerator, which you can then cancel with the denominator.

Comment: Consider a related problem: $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{6h}{7h}$.  Clearly the answer is $6/7$, even though taking the limits separately in the numerator and denominator gives $0/0$.  Getting $0/0$ just means that we cannot find the limit by separately taking limits of the numerator and denominator, we must find another method (which often involves simplifying the expression as suggested in the above comment).

Comment: Do you know what "limit" means?  $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) \ne f(a)$.  That *ISN"T* how you do limits (unless you can prove $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=a$ (and if $f(a)$ is not defined then $f(x)$ is *NOT* continuous at $x=a$ and $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) \ne f(a)$.  ..... Review what $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ actually means.

Comment: "Am I wrong to have this conclusion" Yes.   "or am I correct" you are not  "and the answer somehow isn't DNE" it isn't DNE.   "but instead 0"  The answer is not $0$.  Notice if $h = 0.1$ then $\frac {(-4+h)^2-16}h=\frac {(-3.9)^2 - 16}{0.1} = \frac {-0.79}{0.1} = -7.9$.  And if $h=0.01$ then $\frac {(-4+h)^2-16}h=\frac {(-3.99)^2 - 16}{0.01} = \frac {-0.0799}{0.01} = -7.99$.... doesn't look like $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac {(-4+h)^2-16}h=0$

Comment: Not $h\ne 0$.  $h$ *never* is equal to $0$.  $h > 0$ and $h$ is *always* greater than $0$.  You do *not* plug in $h=0$.  You have to do something entirely different.

Comment: The expression "$0/0$" is meaningless in algebra. Importantly, however, *all of differential calculus* is about assigning meaning to expressions that ostensibly evaluate to "$0/0$"! The notion of *limit* doesn't evaluate an expression "*at* a point"; rather, it evaluates the expression *near* a point ... and *nearer* that point ... and *nearer still* ... and determines whether the expression is *suggesting* a value at the point that it simply won't let us evaluate by direct substitution. I like to think [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/462387/409) describes the phenomenon nicely.

Comment: It should be noted that $ \lim_{x\to a}f(x) $ is defined keeping $x\ne a$ in mind. We consider a neibourhood of $a$ and not the value at $a$. Even if the value of $f$ at $a$ is not defined, even then limit of $f$at $a$ may exist. Therefore, you should not jump to conclusion by finding value at $h=0$ in your question. You should analyze the neibourhood of $0$. Checkout the comment by Mr. @Michael for example.

Answer (score 1):

You have to break it like this:
$$\begin{align}\require{cancel}
\lim_{h\rightarrow0} \frac {(-4+h)^2-16}{h}&=\lim_{h\rightarrow0} \frac {(h^2-8.h+16)-16}{h}
\\&=\lim_{h\rightarrow0} \frac {h^2-8.h}{h}\\&=\lim_{h\rightarrow0} \frac {\cancel {h}.(h-8)}{\cancel {h}},\text{as $h\rightarrow0$ doesn't mean $h=0$.}\\&=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}(h-8)\\&=-8
\end{align}$$
So neither $0$ is the answer.