# What does this mathematical sentence mean? "Let $f(x)$ be a function defined on an interval that contains $x=a$, except possibly at $x=a$."

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, functions, definition

What does this mathematical sentence mean?

> "Let $f(x)$be a function defined on an interval that contains $x=a$, except possibly at $x=a$."

How can a function contain $x=a$ "except possibly at $x=a$"? That is so illogical to me.

This is an excerpt out of the definition for $\lim$.

I know there are questions here that have discussed this already, however I think my question is a bit different as it focuses more on the definition as to what it says in relation to limits. My main question, again, is:

How can a function contain $x=a$ "except possibly at $x=a$"?

Comment: Example: $f(x) = \sin(x)/x$ is defined on the interval $I=(-1, 1)$, except at $x=0$.

Comment: "that contains $x=a$" describes the interval. To restate: "Consider an interval that contains $x=a$. Let $f(x)$ be defined on that interval except possibly at $x=a$." Does that help?

Comment: The interval contains $a$. $f(x)$ is defined for all $x$ in the interval, except possibly if $x=a$. No reason to write that the interval contains $x=a$.

Comment: So when we say „that contains $x = a$“. Lets take a = 1 for example. Now lets say we have an interval $]-1,1[$. According to the definition that would mean that the interval contains $a = 1$, except at $a = 1$.Did I understand correctly?

Comment: I think the statement is meaningful without any ambiguity. If you want formalism then $f$ is a function of the form $f:I\setminus \{a\} \to\mathbb {R} $ where $I$ is an open interval with the property $a\in I$. Sometimes one uses the phrase "$f$ is a real valued function defined in a certain _deleted neighborhood_ of $a$". The statement in your question also allows for $f:I\to\mathbb {R} $ where $a\in I$.

Comment: Considering your example of $a=1$ we need to choose interval like $(0,2)$ or $(0,1.1)$ since we need $1$ as a point in this interval. And we can consider $f:(0, 2)\to\mathbb {R} $ as well as functions like $f:(0, 2)\setminus\{1\}\to\mathbb {R} $.

Comment: @MathNoob: The *interval* under consideration should definitely contain $x=a$, but the *function* may-or-may-not be defined there. The idea is that we don't care what happens with the function *at*  $x=a$; we're only concerned about what happens with it *around* $x=a$. This is a concept I try to convey with [the image in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/462387/409).

Comment: Yup, I now see the mistake in my example. Thanks for taking the time guys you really helped me out here.

Comment: This whole statement is poorly written throughout. "Let $f(x)$ be a function..." Is already wrong. I would write this statement as simply "Consider a function $$f: I \backslash \{a\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$ given $a \in I$".

Comment: @K.defaoite But $f$ is only *possibly* not defined at $a$, so it could also be $I\to\mathbb R$.

Comment: Ok, fair enough.

Comment: @OscarCunningham We might want to apply the definition of limit to find $\lim_{x\to 1} f(x)$ where $f: \mathbb R \setminus\{0\}\to \mathbb R$ such that $f(x) = 1/x.$ In that case the domain of $f$ is neither an interval containing $1$ nor such an interval with $1$ deleted. But $f$ **is** defined on the interval $(0,\infty),$ which contains $1,$ as long as we do not interpret "is defined on $I$" to mean "is defined only on $I.$"

Answer (score 3):

It means the same as "let $I$ be an interval containing $a$, and let $f$ be a function to $\mathbb R$ from either $I$ or $I\smallsetminus\{a\}$". Nothing specifies whether $I$ has to be open, closed, or finite, so it should allow any of these possibilities. In particular $I$ could be a closed interval with $a$ as an endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

It means $f(x)$ is defined everywhere in the interval, except that it may or it may not be defined at $x=a.$