# Is $0^{+^{0^+}}=1$ as a limit form?

Tags: limits, analysis, definition

I know that $0^0$ is undefined as a limit form in analysis but what about $0^{+^{0^+}}$? Isn't it equal to 1?

Comment: Why? $\lim_{n\to\infty}(2^{-n})^{1/n}=\frac12$.

Comment: thanks for that clarification

Comment: As I like to say, [*limits are about the journey, not the destination*](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/462387/409). In the context of indeterminant forms, *limits are about the race*. In the case of $0^0$, what you get depends upon how fast each element approaches zero.

Comment: You need to make up your mind if you are interested in $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)\\x,y>0}x^y$ or in $\lim_{x\to 0+}x^x$. The former does not exist. The latter is $1$.