# Why does the hole in a function move over to a different place after simplifying it?

Tags: limits, functions

This might be a very stupid question. I was trying to evalueate the limit of the function as x tends to 1 of (x-1)/(x^2-1).
This function clearly has a hole at that point because it becomes 0/0 but after simplifying it, the function becomes 1/x+1 and now the hole magically disappears. And the limit is clearly 1/2. But now this function has a hole at x=-1.
Arent both of thease function the same? Why does this happen?

Comment: Consider $f(x) = \frac xx$. This is almost the same as the function $g(x) = 1$. Indeed, $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x$ except $x=0$. The difference is that $g$ is defined everywhere, whereas $f$ is not defined at $x=0$. They are not the same function. When you simplify, make a side note that the domain still excludes the "hole".

Comment: For more detailed discussion, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/462199/why-does-factoring-eliminate-a-hole-in-the-limit?rq=1).

Comment: So every time we perform an alegebraic operation to a function , It becomes a different function?

Comment: The hole at $x=-1$ was always there, because $x^2-1=(x+1)(x-1)$.  The hole doesn't "move".  The first hole at $x=1$ is removable and the second hole at $x=-1$ is always there, whether you're talking about $(x-1)/(x^2-1)$ or $1/(x+1)$.

Comment: Not *every* time, because, for instance, $(x+1)(x-1) = x^2-1$ for every possible $x$.  You *do* have to be careful about the domains of functions when you are composing functions that have restricted domains.

Comment: @Dongky What you're missing is the domain. The function "$\frac{x-1}{x^2-1}$, where $x \in \Bbb R \setminus \{-1,1\}$" is identical to the function "$\frac 1{x+1}$, where $x \in \Bbb R \setminus \{-1,1\}$". Note that despite the simplification, the domain did not change.

Comment: Got it! Thank you!

Comment: We do want to replace $\frac{x-1}{x^2-1}:\mathbb{R}\setminus\{\pm1\}\to\mathbb{R}$ by the new function $\frac{1}{x+1}:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, rather than the function $\frac{1}{x+1}:\mathbb{R}\setminus\{\pm1\}\to\mathbb{R}$, since our knowledge that the former is continuous allows us to replaced the limit computation by function evaluation. We could detal with the latter function, sure, but definitely evaluating the function is easier.

Comment: @user85667 - who is this "we", and why do they and you care so much about Dong ky's function? While it is commonly *useful* to remove removable singularities, there are times when it is important instead to recognize that the function is not defined there and let it be.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Not interested.